# Did Sauron prefer his name not to be written or spoken?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

In the Wikipedia entry for Uruk-Hai, it states that some Uruk-Hai had an elf rune, equivalent to the letter "S", painted on them. It then states:

> It was clear the "S" stood for Saruman, considering Sauron's general desire not to have his name written or spoken. [Wikipedia Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruk-hai#Literature)

Although there is no source provided for that quote. Can anyone quote something in the books (or the film, for that matter) about Sauron not liking his name being written or spoken? I haven't heard of that, and although I have my own theories for why he might prefer that, I'd like to see it straight from the books!

Comment: **Sauron** is not his name but a nick name given by his enemies. Instead o S think like if lhe was nick named **"Buttface"** and you will understand better

Comment: I think it would be more interesting to know why he doesn't insist that all his underlings call him by his original name, Mairon ("The Admirable"), or another ego-boosting pseudonym (such as his other aliases like Annatar, "Lord of Gifts", or Artano, "High-Smith").

Comment: @NicolaTalbot These sissy names were useful enough to fool silly superficial elves. But after the Valar cheated and had their boss sink my body, why keep them? Would *you* keep running around as **"Sweety Sweetface"** after you just survived a disfiguring murder attempt that leaves you looking like anything but?

Comment: @Annatar Yes, Lord of Gifts, you're quite right. :-)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Aragorn states this in *The Two Towers* after the death of Boromir.

> 'I have not seen these tokens before,' said Aragorn. 'What do they mean?'
>   'S is for Sauron,' said Gimli. 'That is easy to read.'
>   'Nay!' said Legolas. 'Sauron does not use the Elf-runes.'
>   '**Neither does he use his right name, nor permit it to be spelt or spoken,'** said Aragorn. 'And he does not use white. The Orcs in the service of Barad-dûr use the sign of the Red Eye.' He stood for a moment in thought. 'S is for Saruman, I guess,' he said at length.
>   <sub>The Two Towers - Chapter 1, The departure of Boromir</sub>

Comment: Though as this question goes into, that might not be an absolute prohibition. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46581/why-do-saurons-servants-sometimes-use-the-name-sauron

Comment: @Nolimon I’m not sure what you mean, all I can tell from that question is why have the Orcs been shown to use the name Sauron and the answer suggest poor translation on Frodo’s part.

Comment: We can certainly attribute it to a translation convention, but as written, the Mouth of Sauron appears to use Sauron's right name despite Aragorn saying that isn't done.

Comment: Again the mouth of Sauron can be down to translation. However, that question bears little relevance to this question as this one is really looking for a quote. I could go into those details, but I feel like that should be left for an answer to that question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although this was not explicitly a part of the original question, are you aware of a reasoning behind this preference?

Comment: I’d have to look further into my texts (again on the train), but off the top of my head no, besides the fact that it meant “Abhorred”

Comment: @Jake If you ask why The Deceiver is concealing something, I think the answer would be self-evident.  : ]

Comment: What does Aragorn consider Sauron's "right name"? (Mairon or Sauron?) He must be sufficiently familiar with elvish to recognise it as a nickname. ("S is for Sauron," said Gimli. [...] "Yeah, but that's not his real name," said Aragorn.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Aragorn was fluent in Sindarin, so yes he would’ve known Sauron was a nickname, it’s also almost certain Aragorn would’ve called him Sauron, as he had no reason to show him respect.

Comment: @Edlothiad I was just wondering why Aragorn didn't simply point out that Gimli's assumption that Sauron's name started with an S was incorrect. (Assuming that Gimli doesn't realise that 'Sauron' is just a nickname, otherwise his comment doesn't make sense.) Perhaps Aragorn doesn't want people in general to know Sauron's origins and so is pretending that's his real name?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot saying Sauron starts with an S isn’t false, it’s just not his _right_ name, however there’s no chance Gimli would’ve known that. Aragorn is not after Gimli to make him seem stupid or whatnot, he’s merely clarifying that there are other names Sauron goes by, and he doesn’t use “Sauron”.